# ¿Cómo puedo resolver un error con librerias en grails?

Tags: grails

Estoy usando `grails` en la version 14.0.1, desarrollando una aplicación que se compone de varios plugins, en uno de estos plugins necesito usar un `.jar` externo, por lo que coloco el `.jar` en la carpeta lib del respectivo plugins. Una vez hecho esto puedo utilizar los métodos contenidos en el `.jar` pero ocurre un error al correr la aplicación.

Este es el error:

```
    |Loading Grails 2.5.3
    |Configuring classpath
    Error |
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    Error |
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/usuario/Escritorio/grails- 2.5.3/dist/grails-plugin-log4j-2.5.3.jar!/org/slf4j /impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    Error |
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/usuario/Desarrollo/sdl/sdl /plugins/sdl-extraction/lib/cermine-impl-1.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar! /org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    Error |
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an  explanation.
    Error |
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
```

Por otra parte cuando intento generar una clase controladora en este plugin me lanza otro error

```
     /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dgrails.home=/home/paul/Escritorio/grails-2.5.3 -Dbase.dir=/home/paul/Desarrollo/sdl/sdl/plugins/sdl-extraction -Dtools.jar=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar -Dgroovy.starter.conf=/home/paul/Escritorio/grails-2.5.3/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/paul/Escritorio/grails-2.5.3/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.4.4.jar:/home/paul/Escritorio/grails-2.5.3/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.5.3.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf /home/paul/Escritorio/grails-2.5.3/conf/groovy-starter.conf "generate-controller sdl.extraction.Metadatos -plain-output"|Loading Grails 2.5.3
    |Configuring classpath
     Error |
     SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
     Error |
     SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/paul/Desarrollo/sdl/sdl /plugins/sdl-extraction/lib/cermine-impl-1.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
     Error |
     SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/paul/Escritorio/grails-2.5.3/dist/grails-plugin-log4j-2.5.3.jar!/org/slf4j /impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
     Error |
     SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
     Error |
     SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
     .
     |Environment set to development
      ................................
     |Packaging Grails application
      ................................................Error 
     |
      Error executing script GenerateController: java.lang.NullPointerException (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

¿Puede alguien ayudarme con esto? ¿Algún consejo con respecto?

Comment: Tu problema es de SLF4J poqrue encuentra más de una definición de logger para utilizar y no has declarado cuál debería utilizar. Pero dicho error no hará que tu aplicación no ejecute. Tu problema real es este: *Error executing script GenerateController: java.lang.NullPointerException (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)*. Ejecuta tu aplicación y envía el comando --stacktrace tal como indica para que puedas ver el stacktrace o puedes debuggear tu aplicación para detectar la variable que es `null` y está siendo utilizada. El error parece auto explicatorio.

Comment: de que manera puedo especificar cual es el la definicion del logger que debe utilzar la aplicacion

Comment: Te recomiendo seguir el enlace que te muestra en el log: *See **http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings** for an explanation*. No lo recuerdo muy bien porque al final del día no es realmente un problema serio a corregir.

Comment: MUchas gracias!